# How to mix content with template images in Electron for macos

Tags: macos, electron, icons, react-native-image

[According to Electron docs](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/native-image#template-image)

> "Template images are not intended to be used as standalone images and
> are usually mixed with other content to create the desired final
> appearance."

May I know how to do so? I haven't found any examples of an implementation. I would like to overlay a red badge onto the template image and set it as a menu bar icon.

I've tried to set an image with a red badge as a template image but the colour got removed and it renders as a black/white badge.